# How to begin to solve 2 Trains Pass each other Question

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like some hints on where to begin solving this problem. I read in page 1 of Introduction to Graph Theorey by Richard J. Trudeau. It's supposed to be a pre-college problem and I've taken several college math courses when I was in college many many years ago. Thank you.

Problem:
A train leaves Philadelphia for New York at 3:00 pm and travels at 60 mph. Another train leaves New York for Philadelphia at 3:30 pm and travels at 75 mph. If the distance between the cities is 90 miles, when and at what point will the train pass?

Answer (score 2):

The first train covers $30$ miles in the half hour before the second train starts, so the trains are $60$ miles apart at 3:30. Starting at 3:30 they are approaching each other at a combined speed of $60+75=135$ miles per hour, so they will meet $\frac{60}{135}=\frac49$ hours after 3:30. Now compute the distance covered by the second train in $\frac49$ hours, and you’ll get the distance from New York of the point at which they pass each other.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.

After $t$ hours since 3:00 the two trains have gone $60t$ and $75(t-1/2)$ miles. When they meet, the distances they travelled must sum up to 90 miles.

Comment: so, 90 = 75t + 60t which is then 90/15 = t. So 15 hrs?

Comment: Sorry: there was an error in my answer: I didn't take into account the different starting times. I've corrected now.